# How to block users from screen mirroring app to Chromecast?

Tags: android, chromecast

There are some Android applications, like NFL Mobile, that don't let users view videos from it while the screen is being cast to a Chromecast. So if I casted my screen to the Chromecast, then opened NFL Mobile, then played a video, it would tell me on the TV "Screen casting videos from NFL Mobile is disabled.".

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate that functionality in my own application but can't get it quite right. I thought I'd create a GoogleApiClient for Cast.CastApi and then check to see if Cast.CastApi.getApplicationMetadata() or Cast.CastApi.getApplicationStatus() returned null from the Chromecast. I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html

Comment: "while the screen is being cast to a Chromecast" -- do you mean the Miracast screen mirroring?

Comment: On later versions of Kit Kat and certain devices, you can go to Settings->Display->Cast Screen and it will also cast to a Chromecast.

Comment: (I forgot to mention) Or you can open the Chromecast app and select "Cast Screen" from the menu.

Comment: Did you find a solution?